# understanding copy and mutable copy

Tags: objective-c, copy, semantics, mutable

Consider the following:

```
// BaseClass is both NSCopyable and NSMutableCopyable
@interface MyClass : BaseClass {
    // a bunch of properties
}

// x is a MyClass* local variable in a method
MyClass *a = [x copy];         // a is a strong reference to an immutable copy?
MyClass *b = [x mutableCopy];  // b is a strong reference to a mutable copy?
```

Questions:

1. Can I make any changes to the iVars of a?  If not, what happens if I try to make changes to any of the iVars?  Will I get indeterminate behaviour, e.g., sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, memory corruption, or does compiler prohibit it altogether?
2. Can I make any changes to iVars of b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

1. Yes. No memory corruption, and no compile error if the iVar is accessible.
2. Same as 1.

### Long answer

Mutable and immutable copy is one of the core concepts found in the Apple's Foundation classes, such as `NSString` or `NSArray`. As stated in [`NSCopying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, **the class that has implement "immutable vs mutable" concept must return immutable object for `copyWithZone:`**.

However the immutability of the object is not enforced by the compiler or memory protection, but the class designer must design the class to make it return immutable object upon receiving `copy` message.

In your case, the common way to implement such thing is to make `MyClass` immutable, and subclass to `MyMutableClass` and make it mutable. Your call site should look like:

```
MyClass *a = [x copy];         
MyMutableClass *b = [x mutableCopy];
```

Note that implement mutable/immutable is sometimes quite tedious, so make sure you have enough reason to implement such feature.

Comment: Now suppose that I'm copying a class like SKNode from the SpriteKit library which implements NSCopying but not NSMutableCopying.  when I invoke copy rather than mutableCopy on an SKNode*, given that it doesn't implement NSMutableCopying, do I assume that the object it returns is mutable?  My understanding from your explanation above is that unless there is a mutable version of a class, e.g., SKMutableNode, I can assume that I can modify the returned copy?

Comment: With common scenario, you can assume that. However, it is really depends on the implementation, because `NSCopying` contract does not say anything for that case e.g. it might be deep clone or shallow clone, or anything. I suggest that if the document, e.g. SpriteKit doc, does not clarify the nature of `copy` method, so common sense is very useful here.